# Shared Controls between UITabBarController View

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, xib, xcode-storyboard

I'm currently developing my first iOS App and so far it's going great. However now I want to develop a feature, that is a little bit more advanced and I have no idea how to proceed.

My app uses `Core Data` and a `TabBarController` to switch between different `NavigationControllers`.

Now I want to implement a Subview on each Navigation Controller that shows a label and two buttons. The label is an indicator for a timer and the two buttons should start and stop the timer and save a little bit of data if the timer is stopped. This Subview should be continuos between the Tabs, so I want to keep the timer and the state of the buttons.

My idea was to create a xib and loading this xib on the `TabBarController` itself, however I don't know how to accomplish this.

Comment: why same view on all navigation controller? Any specific reason? For solution you can create a singleton instance a view controller and link it with all your navigation controller, but this is actually against the purpose of tab bar controller.

Comment: If I start the timer, the label should begin to display the timer and If I want to switch the navigation controller I want to still be able to see this display of the timer and be able to start and stop it.

Comment: have you created your tab bar controller class? or all linked from storyboard.

Comment: I linked everything together in storyboard.

Comment: Check this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748899/having-a-single-view-visible-in-all-tabs-uitabbarcontroller

Answer (score 0):

I would create the timer in a subclass of the tab bar controller; it's sort of a singleton anyway, and should be present for the whole life of the run. If you create a property there, I'll call it "counter", you can observe it in your content controllers to update your label,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"self.tabBarController.counter" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(NSNumber *)[change valueForKey:@"new"]];
    self.label.text = s;
}
```

You would need to have methods in your tab bar controller to start and stop the timer which could be called from buttons in the content controllers. As for the view with the label and buttons, I wouldn't try adding that to the tab bar controller, I would add it to each of the content controllers. If you're designing the views in the storyboard, you can put it in one controller, then copy and paste into any others that need it.

Comment: The idea with the timers seems smart, I will try this tomorrow. Thanks.